# Как настроить urlManager в Yii2 чтобы показывать изображение c шаблоном "/images/address_city_state_zip_PROPERTY-ID_IMAGE-ID.jpg"?

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-manager

Проблема, в общем, вот в чем:

Изображение загружается по ID из контроллера image.
http://myserver/image/miniature-image/?property_id=44369&image_id=2

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в названии файла изображения были адрес и на конце ID, например вот так:
http://myserver/images/address_city_state_zip_PROPERTY-ID_IMAGE-ID.jpg,
где:

- PROPERTY-ID - ID из базы данных.
- IMAGE-ID - номер картинки

Правило работает для http://myserver/image/miniature-image/?property_id=44369 при **выключенном urlManager** и добавлением в .htaccess правила для Mod_Rewrite:

RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_([0-9]+).jpg$ /index.php?r=image/miniature-image&pid=$2

или

RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_([0-9]+).jpg$ /image/miniature-image&pid=$2

Но это не работает при подключении urlManager.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно реализовать в Yii2?

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу так:
в конфигурации добавил следующее правило:

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'rules' =>  [
   'image/<id:[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+_\d{1,}_\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}.jpg>' => 'image/miniature-image'
  ],
],
```

Создал контроллер с методом actionMiniatureImage

```
public function actionMiniatureImage()
{
  ... делаем парсинг $_GET
  ... извлекаем данные из БД
  ... генерируем изображение
}
```

Вызываем из браузера:

```
http://myserver/image/10-address-city-state-zip_45162_2_0.jpg
```

Используем в HTML:

```
<img src="http://myserver/image/10-address-city-state-zip_45162_2_0.jpg" alt="10 Address, City, State Zip">
```

В файле .htaccess ничего НЕ меняем.